# chart o grafica en laravel excel

Tags: php, laravel-5, excel, laravel-excel

Estoy desarrollando en laravel 5.4, con la librería laravel Excel, mi archivo Excel generar dos hojas, la primera la genero invocando a una vista, la segunda hoja quiero realizar la grafica, muestra los datos en las columnas de Excel, pero la grafica la muestra vacía no la arma con respecto a los datos este es mi código desde el controlador:

```
Excel::create('Reporte Certificación con Graficos', function($excel) use ($listaDatosReporte, $result1, $result2,$meses, $valores) {
    $excel->sheet('Lista General', function($sheet) use($listaDatosReporte) {    
        $sheet->loadView('reporteCertificacionGrafica.listadoGeneral',compact('listaDatosReporte'));
    });

    $excel->sheet('Lista General grafica', function($sheet) use($result1,$result2,$meses, $valores) { 

        foreach ($result1 as $value) {
               $meses[] = $value['periodo'];
               $valores[] = $value['trabajadores'];
        }

       $sheet->fromArray(
            array(
            array('', 2010, 2011, 2012),
            array('Q1', 12, 15, 21),
            array('Q2', 56, 73, 86),
            array('Q3', 52, 61, 69),
            array('Q4', 30, 32, 0),
            )
        );

        $dataSeriesLabels = array(

            new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$B$2', NULL, 1),   //  2010
            new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$C$2', NULL, 1),   //  2011
            new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$D$2', NULL, 1),   //  2012
        );
        $xAxisTickValues = array(
            new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$A$3:$A$6', NULL, 4),  //  Q1 to Q4
        );  

        $dataSeriesValues = array(
            new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$B$3:$B$6', NULL, 4),
            new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$C$3:$C$6', NULL, 4),
            new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$D$3:$D$6', NULL, 4),
        );

        $series = new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
            \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART,       // plotType
            \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_CLUSTERED,  // plotGrouping
            range(0, count($dataSeriesValues)-1),           // plotOrder
            $dataSeriesLabels,                              // plotLabel
            $xAxisTickValues,                               // plotCategory
            $dataSeriesValues                               // plotValues
        );
        $series->setPlotDirection(\PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_BAR);

        $plotArea = new \PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea(NULL, array($series));
        $legend = new \PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(\PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, NULL, false);
        $title = new \PHPExcel_Chart_Title('barras');
        $yAxisLabel = new \PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Value ($k)');
        //    Create the chart
        $chart = new \PHPExcel_Chart(
        'chart1',       // name
        $title,         // title
        $legend,        // legend
        $plotArea,      // plotArea
        true,           // plotVisibleOnly
        0,              // displayBlanksAs
        NULL,           // xAxisLabel
        $yAxisLabel     // yAxisLabel
        );

        //    Set the position where the chart should appear in the worksheet
        $chart->setTopLeftPosition('A10');
        $chart->setBottomRightPosition('H25');

        //    Add the chart to the worksheet
        $sheet->addChart($chart); 
    });

})->export('xlsx');
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]